# Static initializer block in derived nested class

Tags: java, inheritance, inner-classes

assuming the following example:

```
public abstract class A {

  public void readList() {
    for (Integer o : InnerA.INT_LIST) {
      System.out.println(o);
    }
  }

  public static class InnerA {

    protected static List<Integer> INT_LIST;

    static {
      INT_LIST = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      INT_LIST.add(1);
    }
  }
}

public class B extends A {      

  public static class InnerB extends InnerA {
    static {
      INT_LIST.add(2);
    }
  }
}
```

My assumtion was, that when I call

```
new B().readList();
```

the output would be

```
1
2
```

but instead it is

```
1
```

Adding the constructor

```
public B() {
    new InnerB();
}
```

leads to the expected behaviour. I thought since the nested class is static, it gets initialized when a new B object is created (it obviously is when A is initialized).

Can someone please explain this to me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see the implementation of `readList()` first:

```
public void readList() {
  for (Integer o : InnerA.INT_LIST) {
    System.out.println(o);
  }
}
```

It is obviously that it print all elements in the `InnerA`.
Class B extends Class A and doesn't override `readList()` function. So the behavior of `new B().readList()` is print all elemtns in the `InnerA`, too.

Since the `InnerA.INT_LIST` only has a elements added in static block of `InnerA`, it only has 1 elements.

Actually, your code never use class `InnerB`. JVM do not load it so its static block is not executed.

Comment: Yes correct, class B never loads because of lazy loading. So, the static initializer never executes.

Comment: Ok, did not know about this lazy loading. So I either override `readList()` or add the `new InnerB()` in the constructor of B. Thanks **EDIT** overriding `readList()` and iterating through `InnerB.INT_LIST` does not work either. The only thing that works is calling `new InnerB()` in the constructor of B.